# React-router dynamic path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have 2 dynamic paths:

path=":object/:category";

path=":some/:thing"

:object can be one of ["women", "men", "kids"];
:category can be one of ["clothes", "shoes"]

How to say react-router, that if first path doesn`t fit for :object/:category, then a want to try ":some/:thing" as second try?

// **Edit:**
I am gonna try another way: is there way to write this code in more concise way:

```
<Route
  path="womens/:category"
  element={
    <Suspense fallback={"Loading ..."}>
      <CatalogPage />
    </Suspense>
  }
/>
<Route
  path="mens/:category"
  element={
    <Suspense fallback={"Loading ..."}>
      <CatalogPage />
    </Suspense>
  }
/>
<Route
  path="girls/:category"
  element={
    <Suspense fallback={"Loading ..."}>
      <CatalogPage />
    </Suspense>
  }
/>
<Route
  path="boys/:category"
  element={
    <Suspense fallback={"Loading ..."}>
      <CatalogPage />
    </Suspense>
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to say react-router, that if first path doesn't fit for
> `":object/:category"`, then a want to try `":some/:thing"` as second
> try?

You can't have two routes with the same path specificity. In other words, a route with `path=":object/:category"` is identical to a route with `path=":some/:thing"` in terms of route matching; they will have the same route rank/score. You'll need to differentiate the routes somehow.

> Is there way to write this code in more concise way:
>
> ```
> <Route
>   path="womens/:category"
>   element={
>     <Suspense fallback={"Loading ..."}>
>       <CatalogPage />
>     </Suspense>
>   }
> />
> <Route
>   path="mens/:category"
>   element={
>     <Suspense fallback={"Loading ..."}>
>       <CatalogPage />
>     </Suspense>
>   }
> />
> <Route
>   path="girls/:category"
>   element={
>     <Suspense fallback={"Loading ..."}>
>       <CatalogPage />
>     </Suspense>
>   }
> />
> <Route
>   path="boys/:category"
>   element={
>     <Suspense fallback={"Loading ..."}>
>       <CatalogPage />
>     </Suspense>
>   }
> />
> ```

You could make this part of the routing code more ***DRY*** by mapping the routes.

Example:

```
import {
  ...,
  generatePath
} from 'react-router-dom';

...

return (
  ...
  {["womens", "mens", "girls", "boys"].map(type => (
    <Route
      key={type}
      path={generatePath(":type/:category", { type })}
      element={
        <Suspense fallback={"Loading ..."}>
          <CatalogPage />
        </Suspense>
      }
    />
  ))}
  ...
```